# Reversing an integer in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to reverse an integer in F#. I have the following approach:

```
//let the number be n
rev = 0
while(n != 0){
    rev = rev * 10 + n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
// rev now contains the reverse integer of n
```

I'm new to F#, and I don't know the the idiomatic syntax to achieve this implementation. I don't want to reverse the number by converting it to string first. How can this implementation be done in F# in an idiomatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a recursive inner function that you call like so.

```
 let reverse n =
     let rec revInner n rev =
         match n with
         | 0 -> rev
         | _ -> revInner (n / 10) (rev * 10 + n % 10)
     revInner n 0

reverse 43221 // -> 12234
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have imperative loops such as a `while` look to convert it to a recursive function. In this case you need an inner function that is recursively called. The first pattern match deals with the termination condition of the `while`, the second deals with the core `while`execution:

```
  let revNum number =
    let rec loop rev = function
    | 0 -> rev
    | fwd ->  loop (rev*10 + fwd%10) (fwd/10)
    loop 0 number;;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had another query. Is recursion preferred over iterative loops in F#? If so, could you tell me why?

Comment: Yes it is. With recursion you can avoid mutable values, by providing state changes as  a parameter in the next recursive call. One of the appeals and powers of functional languages is immutability. As you transition from an imperative and default mutable language this is one of the first challenges to help grok a functional language.